# PANDAS How to compare two files, json, xml to excel

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, compare

I have two files, for example

1. Excel

| ID | Price | Status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1000 | Free |
| 2 | 2000 | Option |
| 3 | 3000 | Reserved |

2. JSON

```
{
            "id": 1,
            "price": "1000",
            "status": "free",
}
{
            "id": 2,
            "localization": "2000",
            "reference": "Option",
}
{
            "id": 3,
            "localization": "3000",
            "reference": "Reserved",
}
```

How I should compare these files? Which commands should be useful?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `pandas` for this:

```
from pandas.testing import assert_frame_equal
df1 = pd.read_excel("your excell file path")
df2 = pd.read_json("your json file path") # or you can create using pd.DataFrame.from_dict(your_dict)

assert_frame_equal(df1, df2)  # this will check if two dataframes are equal or not
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer <3 

Can you explain to me one more issue, sometimes I have different keys, it is possible to put in a rule? For example, let's change json's id to ```x_id```.  Or it is in another place, for example after ```price```. When excels table is the same as in my question.

Comment: yes if you have different column names then we can rename the column once we create dataframe out of file.

Comment: Okay, I'll try it. But I'm not sure about it, because `id` is extremely complicated.


edit: I would like to say thank you, again :)